# pine script with multiple Indicator EMA, Volume & Bollinger

Tags: pine-script

in which I placed multiple indicators with EMA, Vwap Bolinger band.
Now I want to add Volume too. But when I added it will hide all Indicators. Please see the below script.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © makkanimation

//@version=4
study("Vol in Base asset 20MA", "", true, format.volume, overlay=true, scale=scale.none)

EMA1=input(21)
EMA2=input(55) 
EMA3=input(100)
EMA4=input(200)


exponential = input(true, title="Exponential MA")
src = close

ma21 = exponential ? ema(src, EMA1) : sma(src, EMA1)
ma55 = exponential ? ema(src, EMA2) : sma(src, EMA2)
ma100 = exponential ? ema(src, EMA3) : sma(src, EMA3)
ma200 = exponential ? ema(src, EMA4) : sma(src, EMA4) 

// VWAP
price = input(type=input.source, defval=hlc3, title="VWAP Source")
enable_vwap = input(true, title="Enable VWAP")
vwapResolution = input(title = "VWAP Resolution", defval = "", type=input.resolution)
vwapFunction = vwap(price)
vwapSecurity = security(syminfo.tickerid, vwapResolution, vwapFunction)

plot(ma21, color=color.new(color.green, 0), title="[E]MA21")
plot(ma55, color=color.new(color.red, 0), title="[E]MA55")
plot(ma100, color=color.new(color.orange, 0), title="[E]MA100")
plot(ma200, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), title="[E]MA200")
plot(enable_vwap ? vwapSecurity : na, title="VWAP", color=color.navy, linewidth=2, transp=0, editable=true) // All TimeFrames 

bollinger = input(false, title="Bolinger Band")
bolingerlength = input(20,"Length")
// Bollinger Bands
bsrc = input(close, title="Source")
mult = input(2.0, title="std dev", minval=0.001, maxval=50)
basis = sma(bsrc, bolingerlength)
dev = mult * stdev(bsrc, bolingerlength)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
plot(bollinger ? basis: na, color=color.red, title="Bol Basic")
p1 = plot(bollinger ? upper: na, color=color.blue, title="Bol Upper")
p2 = plot(bollinger ? lower: na, color=color.blue, title="Bol Lower")
fill(p1, p2, title="Bol Background")


//Make the moving average user configurable
HIM1 = "1. Historical High"
HIM2 = "2. Highest in last..."
showMA = input(true)
scaleFactor = 100 / input(30, "% of vertical space used", step = 10, maxval = 100)
hiMethod = input(HIM2, "High point method", options = [HIM1, HIM2])
hiMethod2Len = input(400, "  2. Length", minval = 2, step = 100)

//Get volume for current bar and multiply with vwap
vInverse = volume * vwap

//Plot fiat volume.
plot(vInverse, color = color.orange, title="VolumeBTC", style=plot.style_columns, transp=30) //Originally: transp=65

//Plot 20 candle moving average (changable in settings)
plot(showMA ? sma(vInverse,20) : na, color = color.white, title="Volume MA", style=plot.style_area, transp=65)

//Plot high line to scale down the columns.
var histHi = 0.
histHi := max(histHi, nz(vInverse, histHi))
limit = hiMethod == HIM1 ? histHi : highest(vInverse, hiMethod2Len)
plot(limit * scaleFactor, "Historical High", #00000000)
```

Please help me. I want to show all at one place.

Answer (score 1):

You can't accomplish what you are trying to do. Especially with `scale = scale.none`. Your BB will not match the chart candles because of this and because the volume will establish the range of the script's scale which won't remotely line up with your candles. You will need to have them as separate scripts with separate scales. The BB/MA using the chart's scale and another script with `scale.none` to put your volume on the bottom of the chart.